# Manipulated shortcode output

Tags: shortcode

I have a problem with a plugin I developed that registers a shortcode. The shortcode returns a string with valid HTML but some themes seems to manipulate the HTML returned by the shortcode, and I really can't understand what is the reason.

For example, this is the correct output of my shortcode:

```
<div class="tile">
<a>
    <img src="0.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
        <p>Kate</p>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

and this is the output I get with some theme:

```
<div class="tile">
<a>
    <img src="0.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
        <p>Kate</p>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
<p></p></a></div>
```

As you can see there is some extra tag after the closing of the 'caption' DIV.

Maybe these themes apply some kind of HTML validation/sanitization?

Comment: What's the code you're using to generate the HTML (the function add_shortcode is using)?

Comment: "some themes" namely?

Comment: Last theme was http://themeforest.net/item/striking-premium-corporate-portfolio-wp-theme/128763 

I can't post the code I use but is simply something like:

$html = "";
$html .= "<div>";
...
$html .= "</div>;

return $html;

Comment: Does it happen with Twenty Fourteen? Or Twenty Thirteen?

Comment: It doesn't happen with the TwentyFourteen nor with Twenty Thirteen, it happens with some other themes, like  http://themeforest.net/item/striking-premium-corporate-portfolio-wp-theme/128763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting caught in some `wpautop()` replacements. Many people find the defualt WordPress `wpautop()` filter to be frustrating. So often in highly customized themes, there is a homegrown replacement.

For example, the theme you mentioned has a replacememt for some of the default WordPress filters. You can see a thread about it here... http://kaptinlin.com/support/discussion/1835/disable-automatic-p-tags/p1

The only recommendation I can make is to remove the clean formatting ( indents, newlines, etc. ) and see if that helps. Don't give the filters anything to wrap.

Comment: **Thank you** very much! I see the theme author suggests to edit the sources of the theme... I don't like that at all but at least I know what is the problem.